# Enum to String conversion during Spring batch import fails

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-batch

I'm creating a Spring batch job using Spring Boot and Hiberna but I'm experiencing a problem during the insert. This is the relevant part of the code:

```
@Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<OphthalmicLens> writer(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<OphthalmicLens>()
                .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .sql("INSERT INTO OphthalmicLens (`createdBy`,`createdDate`,`lastModifiedBy`,`lastModifiedDate`,`sid`,`version`,`manufacturer`,`manufacturerCode`,`name`,`sku`,`upc`,`cylinder`,`design`,`diameter`,`index`,`material`,`source`,`sphere`,`type`) VALUES (:createdBy,NOW(),:lastModifiedBy,NOW(),UUID(),:version,:manufacturer,:manufacturerCode,:name,:sku,:upc,:cylinder,:design,:diameter,:index,:material,:source,:sphere,:type)")
                .dataSource(dataSource).build();
    }
```

The property design is an enumeration:

```
public enum OphthalmicDesign {
    SPHERIC, ASPHERIC, ATORIC, BIASPHERIC
}
```

that is used in my `OphthalmicLens` beans as this:

```
@NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private OphthalmicDesign design = OphthalmicDesign.SPHERIC;
```

I'm using Mysql 5.7 and that column in the database is mappes as a VARCHAR(255) as expected.

When I run the job I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05~r...' for column 'design' at row 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:210) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:185) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:192) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:218) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchedInserts(ClientPreparedStatement.java:768) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:444) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:839) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar:8.0.11]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:128) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:?]
```

I understand the problem is the enum is not converted to a String. I could solve the problem using a different `BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider` but I think that would be overkilled and I would loose advantage of Spring facilities.

Do you have an hint to tell Spring/Hibernate to automatically convert that enum to a String even when I use Spring Batch?

Comment: You are using Hibernate to manage your entities but the `JdbcBatchItemWriter` to write them. Is there something preventing you from using the `HibernateItemWriter`? This writer knows how to map fields to the correct type according to your mapping when saving items.

Comment: What if we have that column 'design' as VARCHAR and then we have another get method separately to return ENUM to outside. The column 'design' is just used for data mapping. Outside never use that column directly. They will use a 'get' method which return ENUM

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I need to do a native query for performance reason. Acntually in my query I do a INSERT () VALUES() ON UPDATE ()

Comment: @NghiaDo I gave me a good idea. I changed it a bit: I created a getDesignString() and I use that field. Maybe it's not the most elegant way to resolve it.

Comment: Normally what I have done is, Entity will be mapped directly to Database schema and then I map from Entity to Model Pojo and return to Business layer. In this case 'design' as VARCHAR will be in DB entity and 'design' as ENUM will be in Model Pojo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instruct the `BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider` to return the `VARCHAR` type for the field `design` as follows:

```
@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<OphthalmicLens> writer(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<OphthalmicLens>()
            .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<OphthalmicLens>() {
                @Override
                public SqlParameterSource createSqlParameterSource(OphthalmicLens item) {
                    return new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(item) {
                        @Override
                        public int getSqlType(String paramName) {
                            if (paramName.equalsIgnoreCase("desing")) {
                                return Types.VARCHAR;
                            }
                            return super.getSqlType(paramName);
                        }
                    };
                }
            })
            .sql("INSERT INTO OphthalmicLens (`createdBy`,`createdDate`,`lastModifiedBy`,`lastModifiedDate`,`sid`,`version`,`manufacturer`,`manufacturerCode`,`name`,`sku`,`upc`,`cylinder`,`design`,`diameter`,`index`,`material`,`source`,`sphere`,`type`) VALUES (:createdBy,NOW(),:lastModifiedBy,NOW(),UUID(),:version,:manufacturer,:manufacturerCode,:name,:sku,:upc,:cylinder,:design,:diameter,:index,:material,:source,:sphere,:type)")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .build();
}
```